# Optimise raster size

Tags: python, raster, gdal, optimization

I have a raster that represents a classification, this means each pixel can contain a value in a small set (for instance [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]). My file is around 2.4 MB which is pretty small considering that it is 5000x5000 pixels. When I create a naive copy using python gdal bindings the output file is 100 MB, around 40 times bigger! (by naive, I mean, I open the raster, extract the data array and write it to a new raster, using gdal_translate yields same result). Looking closely to both files using gdalinfo I see something interesting, in the original file:

```
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

in the new file:

```
Band 1 Block=5000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I guess that somehow the tif format can optimise the size when it finds redundant information, for example 256x256 pixel blocks with the same value. The question is, how can I write in 256x256 blocks instead of 5000x1 blocks?

Comment: If you're not interested in using the correct datatype, then you really aren't interested in a solution.

Comment: @Vince I didn't write the code that generated the original raster, I know how to solve that problem. I wanted to focus on the problem I can't handle. I added the note to prevent obvious remarks. The question has been modified.

Comment: Use the `TILED=YES` creation option, see http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html

Comment: @BradHards Is it possible to use that option with python?

Comment: It is possible. How depends on the writing approach you've taken (which I can't see from here...). There is an example in the standard gdal tutorial (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) - basically its just part of a list as the last argument to `CreateCopy()`.

Comment: Tiled 256x256 blocks or striped 1x5000 organization makes only marginal difference. Your original image must be compressed while the new is not. Check with gdalinfo.

Comment: Use compression, i.e `gdal_translate etc.. -co compress=deflate` or `compress=lzw`.